# Is there a convention for where to store crash-recovery files?

Tags: windows, file-handling

I work on an application where we have the potential to attempt a file save in the top-level exception handler. The intention would be save a file which can then be sent into the support team, validated for corruption, and restored as far as possible. (We have a small enough customer base to work like this.)

Is there a convention for where to store such a file? I've seen `%APPDATA%/Local/Temp` used for one program - is that a mainstream idea, or just a one-off? Or would it be entirely up to me? Ideally, the user will be able to retrieve this file themselves. (AppData is normally hidden by default, I think?)

Comment: If you are asking about the Windows o/s, then please tag the question accordingly. The more information you can give us, the more help we can give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw with using [user]/AppData/Local/Temp is that it's a location that users (and tools) will delete to free hard drive space.  If you want these files to stay around, I would avoid using Temp.

If you look at your %APPDATA% folder, you'll see that a common convention to use is %APPDATA%/[Vendor]/[Application] for any user specific data that an application wants to save.

For example, I have:

%APPDATA%/Microsoft/Office

%APPDATA%/JetBrains/Resharper

%APPDATA%/Adobe/Acrobat

Comment: Thanks 17. I'd thought of %APPDATA% as more 'settings' sort of files, but looking through, I did find a couple of corrupted/crash log style files. Cheers.